# how to send an event as pageview to google analytics

Tags: ruby, google-analytics

Currently we send events from the backend and the pageviews from our app to the GA. But we are not able to see the behavioral flow from the app pages to the events.

So, According to me if we send the events as the pageviews also then it will be automatically shown in the GA.

So how to send any event as pageview to GA. Is it recommended to do?

If there is some other way to do that please tell us.

Comment: I suggest to use Tag Manager: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/

Answer (score 1):

You can track the event as virtual pageview. A virtual pageview is a hit which Google Analytics track as 'pageview', even when no new web page has actually been loaded into a web browser.

Instead of the event code you can use the following code (for example when the user clicks on a button):

```
ga('send', 'pageview', '*name of your virtual page*');
```

It is an improper use of pageview (I refer to tracking all events as if they were page views) but everything is relative to what you actually need to trace and how you want to see it in the reports.